# PayPal Mobile Express - "Payment cannot be made using mobile device"

Tags: android, iphone, ios, paypal

We have implemented mobile express checkout library in our iPhone and Android apps. However many of the users can't make any payments from the mobile. We have an error "Your payment cannot be made using mobile device" http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/6449/img0617.png . So the problems is only with some accounts. Some accounts work fine, the others don't.
I posted the issue to x.com forum, no help there yet https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/mobile-express-checkout-library/payment-cannot-be-made-using-mobile-device

Comment: Have you tried posting this question in https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/mobile-developers ?

Comment: Is this somehow related to the OS version of device?

Comment: Can this problem be connected with my account? My account is registered for Ukraine. So could it be that mobile payments are restricted from Ukraine?

Comment: Have you used [Mobile Express Checkout Library](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/sdk#6) before?

Answer (score 0):

So I got a message from PayPal merchant support that mobile payments from Ukraine are not supported by PayPAl.